# Running into TS error "Property 'exact' does not exist on type' with react-router"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

My app fails to compile because typescript throws the below error:

```
Type '{ path: string; exact: true; render: () => Element; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes
 & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Component<RouteProps, any, any>> & Readonly<RouteProps> & Readonly<...>'.
  Property 'exact' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes
  & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Component<RouteProps, any, any>> & Readonly<RouteProps> & Readonly<...>'
```

I'm not sure what's going on, but I'm fairly certain that this issue arose after I installed `@types/react-router@3.0.2` as per a [suggestion](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4820#issuecomment-288742470) on Github, but I'm not sure why.

My dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.4",
  "@types/react-router": "^3.0.2",
  "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.3",
  "connected-react-router": "^6.7.0",
  "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
  "react-router": "^5.1.2",
  "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
}
```

What's weird is that I checked out of master into a fresh branch and installed `@types/react-router`, which threw the same error, which is why I'm certain that the error comes from this package, however running `npm uninstall @types/react-router` doesn't get rid of the error. The only way to get my app to compile is to checkout into master, because otherwise the problem persists.

The problem also persists if I install the latest `@types/react-router@3.0.22`.

[image: img]

What's going on here?

Comment: Can you take a look at this https://codesandbox.io/s/r7k106lr8q?file=/src/index.tsx

Comment: Try updating everything to the latest version: `npx npm-check-update -u` (this will rewrite your `package.json`. Also, remove node_modules and package-lock.json and reinstall packages.

Answer (score 6):

if you are using react router v6, it doesn't support exact anymore.

```
// old - v5 <Route exact path="/" component={MyComponent} />

// new - v6 <Route path="/" element={<MyComponent />} />
```

As stated in their documentation:

> You don't need to use an exact prop on  anymore. This
> is because all paths match exactly by default.

You can refer to this migration guide: [here](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5)